# Deep-link photo albums using URL anchor, without hijacking back button

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm creating a photo slideshow that allows for deep-linking. As a user progresses through the slideshow, the anchor tag in the URL bar updates as well, and if someone visits the URL with the anchor tag, that slide is shown first. Example URL:

http://domain.com/news/some-article-slug/#/slide5

I am doing this by simply passing `window.location.hash` to the object:

```
start: window.location.hash.substring(7), // eg. "#/slide5"

// ...

var startingSlide;
this.start = 0;
this.deeplink = this.options.start != null;

if (this.deeplink) {
  startingSlide = Number(this.options.start);
  if (startingSlide > 0 && startingSlide <= this.total) {
    // use that number as the starting slide
  }
}

// ...

this.slides.bind("switch", function(idx) {
  if (_this.deeplink) {
    return window.location.hash = "/slide" + (idx + 1);
  }
});
```

This all works nicely. My problem is as follows:

As the user looks at slides and the URL anchor updates, this is all registered in the browser's history, so using the browser's back button just goes back through the anchors. What I would like to happen is for the back button to go back to the last loaded page.

Imgur has the exact behavior that I'm looking for. Here's a real example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu8aH.jpg

Imgur's javascript is all minified, though, so I can't really find out how it's being done by reading.

Thanks!

**Update**

I ended up using something like this:

```
var slidePath;

if (this.deeplink) {
  slidePath = [window.location.pathname, "/slide" + (idx + 1)].join("#");
  window.history.replaceState(null, window.title, slidePath);
}
```

I decided not to use History.js for a few reasons - I am trying not to include any more JS libraries on my page, and it was also giving me a bit of trouble right off the bat when I did try to include it. The lack of support for older browsers is okay with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_7) to accomplish this.

```
this.slides.bind("switch", function(idx) {
  if (_this.deeplink) {
    var newUrl = window.location + "#/slide" + (idx + 1);
    return window.history.replaceState(null, window.title, newUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent - I didn't know about all the HTML5 state functionality. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish it using history.js https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/
Check their demo page http://browserstate.github.com/history.js/demo/.

**replaceState** function will do what you need.

history.js will emulate replaceState functionality in HTML4 browsers too - that includes IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! See my update - I ended up not using History.js for a few reasons, but it definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: just want to warn you that unfortunately "older browsers" include IE8 and IE9 which still don't support pushState and replaceState. IE10 will support it.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I tried using History.js to get around this but it ended up complicating things, and to me this minor feature is something that IE users can be without for now.